# How does alarm or any other time based applications work?

Tags: linux, android, ios, events, alarm

I have always been wondering that when we set an alarm on our mobile device, it keeps on checking the system time and tries to match it to the value set. This way, alarms might consume lot of CPU power, and make the mobile device slow in performance.

Not only the alarm application, but also an HTTP server keeps checking for new requests, and also event listeners in JavaScript or any other language keep looking up for events. And there are many more.

These processes should require a lot of computation, so what is the way they manage the tasks so lightly?
How do they make usage of CPU and work accurately without using too much of CPU power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These processes should require a lot of computation, ...

Your assumption is incorrect.
You are not clear as what you mean by *"time based application"*, but I would generalize programs as either requesting a delay (aka sleep) or notification (aka signal) for a short duration (i.e. less than one second or at most several seconds), versus a delay/suspension or notification for a long duration, typically specified by a future clock time and calendar date.
Regardless the processing typically reduces to decrementing (and testing for zero) counters in a list at the timer resolution, which are simple computations using integer arithmetic.

---

A program delay or notification of short duration is typically specified by a time interval relative to the current time.  Such a system call could be named **delay()** or **sleep()** with variations such as **msleep()** and **usleep()** to allow specification of the time duration in units of seconds or sub-seconds.
Such a system call would create a timer entry, where the time duration is converted and stored as a `count` based on the `timer resolution`.  On each tick of the system timer, the `counter` of each timer entry is decremented by one.  A `counter` that changes to zero is an expired timer, and the callback routine of the appropriate process is executed.

The typical Linux desktop has a tick (aka **HZ**) and `timer resolution` of 10 milliseconds.    This timer list is processed (i.e. decremented & tested) on every tick of the system timer.  Hence any time request would effectively be rounded up to the nearest 0.01 second.

The use of Linux for embedded applications prompted the introduction of `high-resolution timers`, which utilizes dedicated timer hardware.  The hrtimer could have a resolution of 1 nanosecond (when supported by the hardware).  Rather than processing the timer list on every tick, a hrtimer interrupt is generated for each expiration.

On a Linux system refer to the file **/proc/timer_list** for timer information (e.g. resolution), including the active timer entries.

---

A program delay or notification of long duration could be specified by a time interval relative to the current time or a specific (i.e. absolute) time and date in the future.  The resolution of long delays and clock events would be at best to the second, so processing of such timed events need only occur once per second (i.e. only 60 times per minute).
If all the timed events are maintained in a chronological-ordered list with delta values, then only the first item in that list needs to be processed (rather than the entire list) each second.  The required processing each second would merely consist of decrementing a counter, and checking for a zero value, i.e. an expired timer.
[The above is a description of an embedded system I wrote.  I don't know how Linux handles relative vs absolute time and short vs long intervals.]

Note that Unix/Linux traditionally uses a 'count of seconds since the epoch' to represent clock time & calendar date, so manipulating time intervals or elapsed time or absolute time (i.e. clock time & calendar date) can be accomplished with integer values representing seconds.  Clock and calendar calculations are simple integer arithmetic operations.

Presumably Microsoft Windows uses a similar scheme.  Maintaining clock and calendar information internally as seconds, minutes, hours, day (of month), month, and year leads to complex processing and potential buggy software.  For instance DVR products based on MStar firmware (for the MStar 7816 SoC) all had bugs that prematurely terminated scheduled recordings at midnight (i.e. the start of a new day).  When the time & date are represented as a single count of seconds (since the epoch), the transition between days becomes transparent/irrelevant, and would not cause such a midnight bug.

---

A  time-based job scheduler such as the **crond** daemon would also not *"require a lot of computation"*.  The time resolution for specifying execution of a job is the `minute`.  In other words, the **crontab** only has to be reviewed once every minute, and the daemon calls **sleep()** to pass the time.  Unless the system is overloaded, the **crond** daemon does not impose a significant load on the processor.

---

The prior descriptions are for handling time events using software, which requires the system to have power and be executing.  But the system may need to handle an event when the hardware is sleeping/suspended.  For that situation additional hardware is required, and one typical solution is to have a realtime clock/calendar (aka RTC) with independent power (e.g. its own battery).  A basic RTC can maintain time while the computer system is powered off.  A more-capable RTC will have an alarm capability, where a future time and date can be specified to generate an interrupt, which in turn could be utilized to wake-up the sleeping system.